# Apache Flink PubSub Connector : Slow Processing

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using [flink pubsub connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/pubsub/) for reading messages from gcp pubsub source and doing aggregration over that data with windowing and eventually persisting that data to google cloud storage. My goal is to do daily aggregration of data.

### Additional Configurations

- I thought HashMap based state backend could be creating memory bottleneck so I've configured rocksdb as state backend and enabled incremental checkpoints as well.
- I tried to make window smaller than 1 day for e.g. 1 hour but still pipeline is slow.

### Running

- I've run it in standalone fashion with max heap configured to 4GB but throughput is poor and responsiveness is bad for e.g. it stops processing messages sometimes.
- I've also run it on Flink cluster with two task managers(configured with 512 MB heap) but again acknowledgments are slow. overall pipeline is slow.

### Issue

I realised it is not working optimally, it gets stuck after certain time and some issues pop up like Java Heap Space is full or unable to upload state.
Checkpointing frequency is 10 seconds and ack deadline is 600seconds but messages are not processed timely and there is a huge backlog of messages.
Not sure if there is a configuration issue or hardware limitation or I am using it in a wrong way.

### Setup

Flink Version 1.18.1

Java Version 17

### Code

```
package joda.data;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.Encoder;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.CheckpointConfig;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.OutputFileConfig;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.WindowFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingProcessingTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSource;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import joda.data.bucketassigner.CsvGcsBucketAssigner;
import joda.data.model.MechanicalGroupIdentifier;
import joda.data.model.MechanicalRequestMetric;
import joda.data.serde.MechanicalMetricDeserializer;
import joda.etl.core.aspsp.AspspEndpointIdExtractor;
import joda.etl.core.aspsp.MechanicalIdExtractor;

public class PubSubToGcsCsv {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PubSubToGcsCsv.class);
    private static final String GCP_PROJECT = System.getenv().getOrDefault("GCP_PROJECT", "");
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = System.getenv().getOrDefault("SUBSCRIPTION_NAME", "");
    private static final String CHECKPOINTING_LOCATION = System.getenv().getOrDefault("CHECKPOINTING_LOCATION", "");
    private static final long CHECKPOINTING_INTERVAL = Long.parseLong(System.getenv().getOrDefault("CHECKPOINTING_INTERVAL", "10000"));
    private static final String RESULT_LOCATION = System.getenv().getOrDefault("RESULT_LOCATION", "");
    private static final boolean LOCAL_EXECUTION = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getenv().getOrDefault("LOCAL_EXECUTION", "false"));
    private static final int MAX_PULL_MESSAGES_FROM_SUBSCRIPTION = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("MAX_PULL_MESSAGES_FROM_SUBSCRIPTION", "100"));
    private static final int PULL_MESSAGES_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("PULL_MESSAGES_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS", "30"));
    private static final int PULL_MESSAGES_RETRIES = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("PULL_MESSAGES_RETRIES", "7"));
    private static final int MESSAGE_RATE_LIMIT = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("MESSAGE_RATE_LIMIT", "100"));
    private static final int AVAILABLE_PROCESSORS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private static final int TUMBLING_PROCESSING_WINDOW_FOR_RAW_MECHANICAL_DATA = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("TUMBLING_PROCESSING_WINDOW_FOR_RAW_MECHANICAL_DATA", "60"));
    private static final int TUMBLING_PROCESSING_WINDOW_FOR_AGGREGRATED_MECHANICAL_DATA = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("TUMBLING_PROCESSING_WINDOW_FOR_AGGREGRATED_MECHANICAL_DATA", "60"));
    private static final boolean APPROXIMATE_ENDPOINT_MAPPING = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getenv().getOrDefault("APPROXIMATE_ENDPOINT_MAPPING", "true"));
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(GCP_PROJECT.isBlank() || SUBSCRIPTION_NAME.isBlank() || CHECKPOINTING_LOCATION.isBlank() || RESULT_LOCATION.isBlank()) {
            LOG.info("One of Environment variable among GCP_PROJECT, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, CHECKPOINTING_LOCATION, RESULT_LOCATION is undefined");
        }
        if(!LOCAL_EXECUTION) {
            // parse input arguments
            final ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

            if (parameterTool.getNumberOfParameters() < 3) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Missing parameters!\n"
                                + "Usage: flink run PubSub.jar --input-subscription <subscription> --input-topicName <topic> --output-topicName <output-topic> "
                                + "--google-project <google project name> ");
                return;
            }
            String projectName = parameterTool.getRequired("google-project");
            String subscriptionName = parameterTool.getRequired("input-subscription");
            String checkpointLocation = parameterTool.getRequired("checkpoint-location");
            String resultLocation = parameterTool.getRequired("result-location");
            LOG.info("Checkpoint location {}", checkpointLocation);
            runFlinkJob(projectName, subscriptionName, LOCAL_EXECUTION, checkpointLocation, 10000, resultLocation);
        } else {
            runFlinkJob(GCP_PROJECT, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, LOCAL_EXECUTION, CHECKPOINTING_LOCATION, CHECKPOINTING_INTERVAL, RESULT_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    private static void runFlinkJob(
            String projectName, String subscriptionName, boolean local, String checkpointLocation, long checkpointInterval, String resultLocation) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env;
        if(local) {
            env = LocalStreamEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
        } else {
            env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        }
        // Checkpoint Configurations
        env.enableCheckpointing(checkpointInterval);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(100);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage(checkpointLocation);

        env.getCheckpointConfig().setExternalizedCheckpointCleanup(
            CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION
        );
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage(checkpointLocation);

        // Incremental Checkpoints
        // https://flink.apache.org/2018/01/30/managing-large-state-in-apache-flink-an-intro-to-incremental-checkpointing
        env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend(checkpointLocation + "/rocksdb/", true));

        PubSubSource<MechanicalRequestMetric> pubSubSource = PubSubSource.newBuilder()
                .withDeserializationSchema(new MechanicalMetricDeserializer())
                .withProjectName(projectName)
                .withSubscriptionName(subscriptionName)
                .withPubSubSubscriberFactory(MAX_PULL_MESSAGES_FROM_SUBSCRIPTION, Duration.ofSeconds(PULL_MESSAGES_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS), PULL_MESSAGES_RETRIES)
                .withMessageRateLimit(MESSAGE_RATE_LIMIT)
                .build();

        // 4. Create the stream
        DataStream<MechanicalRequestMetric> txnStream =
                env
                        .addSource(
                                pubSubSource,
                                "Mechanical Source"
                        )
                        //.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy)
                        .setParallelism(AVAILABLE_PROCESSORS)
                        .name("MechanicalSource")
                        .uid("MechanicalSource");


        DataStream<Tuple2<MechanicalGroupIdentifier, String>> aggregratedResult = txnStream
                .keyBy(i -> new MechanicalGroupIdentifier(i.getMechanicalId().toString(), i.getEndpoint().toString(), i.getVersion().toString()))
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(TUMBLING_PROCESSING_WINDOW_FOR_AGGREGRATED_MECHANICAL_DATA)))
                .apply(new WindowFunction<MechanicalRequestMetric, Tuple2<MechanicalGroupIdentifier, String>, MechanicalGroupIdentifier, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(MechanicalGroupIdentifier identifier, TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<MechanicalRequestMetric> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<MechanicalGroupIdentifier, String>> collector) throws Exception {
                        int successful = 0;
                        int failedA = 0;
                        int failedT = 0;
                        int unkn = 0;
                        for (MechanicalRequestMetric metric : iterable) {
                            if(metric.getStatus() == 200 || metric.getStatus() == 201 || metric.getStatus() == 204)
                                successful++;
                            else if (metric.getStatus() >= 400 && metric.getStatus() < 500) {
                                failedA++;
                            } else if(metric.getStatus() >= 500 && metric.getStatus() < 600) {
                                failedT++;
                            } else {
                                unkn++;
                            }
                        }

                        String result = LocalDateTime.now() +
                                "," + successful +
                                "," + failedA +
                                "," + failedT +
                                "," + unkn;
                        collector.collect(Tuple2.of(identifier, result));
                    }
                })
            .setParallelism(AVAILABLE_PROCESSORS);

        OutputFileConfig outputFileConfig = OutputFileConfig.builder()
                .withPartSuffix(".csv")
                .withPartPrefix(LocalDate.now().toString())
                .build();

        final StreamingFileSink<Tuple2<MechanicalGroupIdentifier, String>> aggegratedSinkWithoutGSScheme = StreamingFileSink
                .forRowFormat(new Path(resultLocation + "/daily/"), new AggrgratedCustomEncoder("UTF-8"))
                .withOutputFileConfig(outputFileConfig)
                .build();

        aggregratedResult.addSink(aggegratedSinkWithoutGSScheme)
                        .name("CSV Aggregated Sink Daily Dump")
                            .setParallelism(AVAILABLE_PROCESSORS);
        env.execute("Flink Streaming PubSubReader to GCS CSV");
    }

}

class CustomEncoder implements Encoder<Tuple2<String, String>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6865107843734614470L;
    private String charsetName;
    private transient Charset charset;

    public CustomEncoder() {
        this("UTF-8");
    }

    public CustomEncoder(String charsetName) {
        this.charsetName = charsetName;
    }
    @Override
    public void encode(Tuple2<String, String> stringStringTuple2, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        if (this.charset == null) {
            this.charset = Charset.forName(this.charsetName);
        }

        outputStream.write(stringStringTuple2.f1.toString().getBytes(this.charset));
        outputStream.write(10);
    }
}

class AggrgratedCustomEncoder implements Encoder<Tuple2<MechanicalGroupIdentifier, String>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6865107843734614470L;
    private String charsetName;
    private transient Charset charset;

    public AggrgratedCustomEncoder() {
        this("UTF-8");
    }

    public AggrgratedCustomEncoder(String charsetName) {
        this.charsetName = charsetName;
    }
    @Override
    public void encode(Tuple2<MechanicalGroupIdentifier, String> stringStringTuple2, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        if (this.charset == null) {
            this.charset = Charset.forName(this.charsetName);
        }

        outputStream.write(stringStringTuple2.f1.toString().getBytes(this.charset));
        outputStream.write(10);
    }
}
```